# Netezza odbc driver for linux download failed

Tags: download, odbc, driver, netezza

I was trying to download Netezza odbc driver for linux machine, i was following downloading steps from
https://dwgeek.com/download-configure-netezza-linux-odbc-driver.html/

and also tried from

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/HOW-TO-Download-the-Netezza-ODBC-driver?language=en_US

after at selection of fix pack and clicked on continue , i got following error

[image: Error obtained in netezza odbc linux driver]

Unable to solve this error of driver download.
And wanted to know about if netezza drivers are free of cost or paid ?

Answer (score 0):

It requires entitlement i.e. paid for now. There is an ongoing effort to make the drivers freely available.

-Samir